# Get part of image from AForge.Net videosourceplayer

Tags: c#, image-resizing, aforge

Can anybody help me with this problem, please?

I put VideoSourcePlayer control from AForge.Net, a picturebox and a button on my form. When clicking I want to show only a region from current frame to picturebox. I can show the whole frame using this code:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)videoSourcePlayer1.GetCurrentVideoFrame().Clone();
 pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
```

Comment: You can paint the region of interest from the bitmap on an intermediate image with `Graphics.DrawImage`, then assign that intermediate image to the PictureBox.

Comment: Thank you. I solved my problem resizing bitmap and copying region of new bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap bitmap = this.VideoSourcePlayer.GetCurrentVideoFrame();
```